# rails db:migrateができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`rails db:migrate`をしたところ、エラーが出てしまいました。
どうすればいいでしょうか？
教えてください。

```
== 20180629092541 AddActivationToUsers: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:users, :activation_digest, :string)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activation_digest: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "activation_digest" varchar
C:/Users/sk/programming/sample_app/db/migrate/20180629092541_add_activation_to_users.rb:3:in change'
bin/rails:4:in require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activation_digest: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "activation_digest" varchar C:/Users/sk/programming/sample_app/db/migrate/20180629092541_add_activation_to_users.rb:3:in change'  
bin/rails:4:in require' bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: activation_digest
C:/Users/sk/programming/sample_app/db/migrate/20180629092541_add_activation_to_users.rb:3:in change'
bin/rails:4:in require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

C:/Users/sk/programming/sample_app/db/migrate/20180629092541_add_activation_to_users.rb　のコード

```
class AddActivationToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
def change
add_column :users, :activation_digest, :string
add_column :users, :activated, :boolean, default: false
add_column :users, :activated_at, :datetime
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`duplicate column name: activation_digest`と出ているので `activation_digest`というカラムが既に存在しているため失敗しています。
既にカラムが存在しているかどうかを確認してみてください。

またもし最初からmigrationを実行するのであれば`rake db:reset`を実行すれば一度テーブルなどをすべて削除してリセットしたあとにmigrationを実行出来ます。

Comment: rails db:resetできませんでした。Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/sk/programming/sample_app/db/development.sqlite3
Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/sk/programming/sample_app/db/development.sqlite3
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: こちらを参考にしたらよいかと思います。https://qiita.com/KTakata/items/2ce68fed4126a34adb06